# What means "Returns the maximum gain value, which is greater than 1.0." in AudioTrack

Tags: android

I try to amplify my PCM sound before playing it.
It sounds quieter than other sounds on the same system level.
What means "Returns the maximum gain value, which is greater than 1.0." in getMaxVolume() AudioTrack? How greater? In which case? Can AudioTrack really amplify (convert) the input sound.

Comment: it likely means the max volume of the track on it's whole length

Comment: The question was in which case it is greater than 1.0

Comment: well, it was not. At least you did not tell that in the question.

Comment: Really? There are several questions

Comment: you mentioned too many *questioins*, therefore it looks more like you need to get general idea about what it does. Documentation says 1.0 is the minimum level of the gain, which corresponds to total silence (0 db). (as I understand). So basically anything in the track is *greater or equal to 1.0*